# How to list /find all driver files getting compiled while doing make?

Tags: wireless, kernel, makefile

Driver files getting compiled while doing make, is there any ways to list using the makefiles?

Comment: You can find all drivers built after make finishes: `find . -name "*.ko"`.

Comment: Fine, Can we list the files which get compiled to get ".ko" files?

Comment: You can check `make -nd`.